# WPF Window -- Trying to create two size options: constant "normal dimensions" and full-screen

Tags: c#, wpf, resize, titlebar

I am creating a WPF application in which I would like the user to be able to choose between the loaded Window dimensions or full-screen. I have attempted this by doing the following:

Within Window in xaml, I set:

```
<Window x:Class= ...
    ...
    StateChanged="Window1_StateChanged"
    Height=520
    Width = 1000>
```

Within my xaml.cs file, I set:

```
    void Window1_StateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SC: " + this.WindowState);
        if (this.WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SC: " + this.WindowState);
            this.MaxHeight = SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenHeight;
            this.MaxWidth = SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenWidth;
            this.Height = SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenHeight;
            this.Width = SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenWidth;

        }
        else if (this.WindowState == WindowState.Normal || this.WindowState == WindowState.Minimized)
            {
            MinHeight = 520;
            MaxHeight = 520;
            MinWidth = 1000;
            MaxWidth = 1000;
            Console.WriteLine("SC: " + this.WindowState);
        }

    }
```

However the window never maximizes. When I add these two lines in the WindowState.Maximized conditional, I end up losing my titlebar.

```
this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
```

Any ideas as to what's going on? Please let me know if you need more details.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, the issue is that the state and dimensions interact, as the maximize behavior depends on the current min/max window settings, which you aren't changing until _after_ the maximize occurs. It's hard to know what your _exact_ problem is, because there's not a [mcve] here. But it wasn't hard for me to reproduce _some_ undesirable behavior when running code that tries to change the window dimensions after the maximum/normal state change. Unfortunately, I don't have a good work-around.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for your help in understanding it, Peter. Also, thanks for the link. I'll post more complete questions in the future. :)